# Trying to deploy a React app to GitHub pages, but it is redirecting to the README file instead

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, github-pages, npm-scripts

So I have googled this, and tried everything I could think of / found suggested, but really not having any luck so thought I might need to ask for some help.

I'm trying to deploy a React App to GitHub pages, using the gh-pages package, following a tutorial. To try and do this, I've taken the following steps:

- Installed the `gh-pages` package.
- Added a homepage to the package.json, in the `https://<username>.github.io/<repo-name>` format.
- Added predeploy and deploy scripts to the package.json (`"predeploy": "npm run build"," deploy": "gh-pages -d build",`).
- Ran the deploy script, put in my SSH key when prompted, created a `gh-pages` branch
- Set that `gh-pages` branch as the source for the deployed environment in the GitHub settings

I'm not getting the application I've built though - I'm just getting the README file from the repository. I've read half a dozen tutorials now, and a handful of posts on here, but finding they just seem to repeat the same steps and I'm really sure I've followed every step to the letter.

A few of the things I have tried but don't seem to have helped (they were guesses):

- I was using a prebuilt `.gitignore` which ignored the `/build` directory. I removed this from the `.gitignore` - first on the `gh-pages` branch only, and then on the whole thing - and repeated all the steps above both times.
- I tried installing the `gh-pages` package using `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` and `npm install gh-pages --save` (I'd initially just done `npm install gh-pages`).
- I added `-b gh-pages` to the deploy script and ran this script from the main branch.
- I changed the start script from `react-scripts start` to `npm install && react-scripts start`; I didn't think this would help but not really sure whether it has something to do with putting `/node_modules` in the `.gitignore`.

None of these things helped! Still just got the README. I don't know if it might be obvious to someone else what I'm doing wrong - I hope it is! I want to say I'm not very familiar with / haven't really got my head around build scripts, and I haven't deployed a Node app to GitHub before. If someone does spot the problem, I would also like to know what's up rather than just get the code that would fix it!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Oh, I meant to include a link to the repository! Its https://github.com/djbowen95/Hit-the-Bucket

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to see the deployed React app when forking to my own account and running a new deployment (see https://andrewusher.github.io/Hit-the-Bucket/). I see that your `gh-pages` branch is pretty much the same as your `main`, and also has the README, which is why you're seeing it on GH pages. The `gh-pages` branch should only contain the artifacts in the `/build` directory. I'd recommend deleting the `gh-pages` demand on Github (and locally), then running `npm run deploy` again.